# sun - do gamma rays reach radiative zone

Tags: the-sun, galaxy, universe, radiation

So in the sun's core, gamma rays are produced and right away, in the few milimetters, compton scattering happens.

As I understand the compton effect, gamma ray will first collide with free electron, and for the first collision, another gamma ray will be produced(from old one through scattering) - though this gamma ray will have a little bit longer wavelength(though, the difference in wavelengths are so small that new photon is still gamma ray. after so many scattering in the core, at some point, after `x` collisions, the photon will end up being `x-ray`.

**Question 1:** Is the above logic right ?

**Question 2:** do gamma rays escape the core and move into radiative zone ? or only some very small part of gamma rays reach radiative zone ? or all the photons that reach from core to radiative, they're already x-rays ?

Comment: BTW, stellar fusion doesn't only release energy as gamma photons. A substantial amount of the energy is released as the kinetic energy of the fusion products.

Comment: Well fusion itself only produces gamma rays in the sun’s core. Thats what everybody says. Though, due to compton scattering, you go to bigger wavelength photons.

Comment: Giorgi, only part of the fusion output energy is in the form of photons. I have some details (from Wikipedia) here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48281/16685